# Unbalanced binary tree not functioning properly. Node.Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, binary-search-tree

So I was solving a problem for class involving binary search and the algorithm I implemented to solve it worked fine but my hunch is that a slight gamble would be more effective given the parameters of the problem

> The fictional town of HollyBroke, Fl is made up of a 30 x 30 block grid. The streets are named after the presidents of the United States and the avenues are numbered numerically. The infamous two-word arsonist is holding the town hostage. He selects a house every Saturday for destruction by fire and taunts the police department by challenging them to guess the location for each week’s crime. He will answer up 10 guesses with either a “yes”or a “no” answer during his very brief phone call right before he strikes the match. (He won’t stay on the line so the call can’t be trace.)
>   The city wants you to develop a program to provide a quick response when this notorious criminal calls.

The answer to that was easy enough to create an algorithm for but I thought a median-1/median+1 gamble would be more effective. My hunch is that more often than not I will arrive at the conclusion with one extra question to go allowing me to either ask a binary search question about the arsonist or if the game allowed it I would show up with police before the end of the call. If I don't outright solve it beforehand I would have a very small space to search after it was completed, like three or four blocks right next to each other,

This is my code for the "gambling" binary search.

```
`var array = [{"a":30,"b":30,"c":0}]
function findLower(input) {



    var half = Math.floor(input/2);

    if(0 == input%2)

        return (half-1);
    else
        return (half);
};
function findUpper(input) {
    var  half = Math.floor(input/2);

    if(input%2 == 0)
        return (half+1);

    else
        return (half+1);
}
for (var i = 0; i <= 9; i++){
    for (var z = array.length - 1; z >= 0; z--) {
        if (array[z].c = i){        
            if (array[z].a>array[z].b)
                array.push({"a":findLower(array[z].a),"b":array[z].b,"c":array[z].c + 1},{"a":findUpper(array[z].a),"b":array[z].b,"c":array[z].c + 1})
            else
                array.push({"a":array[z].a,"b":findLower(array[z].b),"c":array[z].c + 1},{"a":array[z].a,"b":findUpper(array[z].b),"c":array[z].c + 1})
        }
    };  
}

console.log(array.length);`
```

Its coming up with an absurd array length given that it should be 2^10 +2^9 + 2^8 ..... = 2047
The program is coming up with an array length of 19683

And some of the arrays should most certainly not be 30*14 at node level 10 I'm sure the algorithm was set up properly. I've walked it through two levels by pen and paper and it seems like it should work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

```
   if (array[z].c = i){
```

should be

```
    if (array[z].c == i){
```

its a conditional statement not declaring them equal

Also I was wrong. You only have about a 40% chance of successfully locating the house in 10 guesses.